# 数分アクセスしないだけでApacheが落ちる。

Tags: macos, apache, passenger

Ruby on RailsでWebアプリケーションを構築しているのですが、Apacheが非常に不安定であり、数分間アクセスしないだけで、落ちるという状況です。 
エラーログを記載させていただきます。 
もし解決法、思い当たる点等ございましたら、ご教授いただきたく存じます。 
よろしくお願いします。

**OS, Apache, and passenger version**

```
YOSUKESMACBOOKPRO13 /etc/apache2% sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.2
BuildVersion:   15C50

YOSUKESMACBOOKPRO13 /etc/apache2% passenger -v
Phusion Passenger 5.0.23

YOSUKESMACBOOKPRO13 /etc/apache2% apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix)
Server built:   Jul 31 2015 15:53:26
```

**/var/log/apache2/error_log**

```
[Tue Jan 05 13:14:52.414672 2016] [core:info] [pid 2372] AH00096: removed PID file /private/var/run/httpd.pid (pid=2372)
[Tue Jan 05 13:14:52.414742 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2372] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4760 2386/0x70000018a000 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:507 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4760 2388/0x700000104000 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:397 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4761 2388/0x7fff761e5000 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:467 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4761 2386/0x7fff761e5000 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:876 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4761 2386/0x7fff761e5000 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:794 ]: Disconnecting long-running connections for process 2424, application /Users/BandAppServer/Sites/BandAppServer/InFlames (development)
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4762 2388/0x700000104000 Ser/Server.h:444 ]: [UstRouter] Shutdown finished
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4762 2386/0x7fff761e5000 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:794 ]: Disconnecting long-running connections for process 2440, application /Users/BandAppServer/Sites/BandAppServer/InFlames (development)
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4762 2386/0x7fff761e5000 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:794 ]: Disconnecting long-running connections for process 2429, application /Users/BandAppServer/Sites/BandAppServer/ArchEnemy
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4762 2388/0x70000020a000 Ser/Server.h:758 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4763 2388/0x70000020a000 Ser/Server.h:444 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4765 2386/0x70000018a000 Ser/Server.h:758 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4765 2386/0x70000018a000 Ser/Server.h:444 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4774 2386/0x700000290000 Ser/Server.h:758 ]: [ServerThr.2] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4774 2386/0x700000290000 Ser/Server.h:444 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4775 2388/0x7fff761e5000 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:498 ]: Passenger UstRouter shutdown finished
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4776 2386/0x700000396000 Ser/Server.h:758 ]: [ServerThr.3] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4777 2386/0x700000396000 Ser/Server.h:444 ]: [ServerThr.3] Shutdown finished
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4778 2386/0x70000049c000 Ser/Server.h:758 ]: [ServerThr.4] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4780 2386/0x70000049c000 Ser/Server.h:444 ]: [ServerThr.4] Shutdown finished
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4782 2386/0x7000005a2000 Ser/Server.h:758 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4782 2386/0x7000005a2000 Ser/Server.h:444 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.4784 2386/0x7fff761e5000 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:794 ]: Disconnecting long-running connections for process 2429, application /Users/BandAppServer/Sites/BandAppServer/ArchEnemy
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.7847 2386/0x7fff761e5000 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:794 ]: Disconnecting long-running connections for process 2424, application /Users/BandAppServer/Sites/BandAppServer/InFlames (development)
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:52.7848 2386/0x7fff761e5000 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:794 ]: Disconnecting long-running connections for process 2440, application /Users/BandAppServer/Sites/BandAppServer/InFlames (development)
[ 2016-01-05 13:14:53.1069 2386/0x7fff761e5000 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:942 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
```

Comment: MacBookでサーバ立ててるようですが、メモリクリーナなどMac上で動作している他のアプリは無いんでしょうか？プロセスを殺されているような気がするのですが……

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
メモリクリア系は動作しないよう設定しております。
いまのところ、他サイトでご助言いただいたpassenger.confのPassengerMaxPreloaderIdleTimeを0に設定したところ落ちないようになりました。
ただメモリ関係でスワップが起こったなどの状況は未だ試していないので、チェックさせていただきます。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic Termination という機能があるそうで もしかすると httpd が自動停止されてるかもしれません。
次のコマンドで Automatic Termination は無効化できるそうなので試してみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSDisableAutomaticTermination -bool true
```